# "demands that he abandon" vs. "demands that he abandons"

Tags: subjunctives, third-person-singular

On a site about movies, I read the following:

> While Nader defaults to self-righteousness after his wife demands that he abandon his Alzheimer’s-ridden father, Maadi shades the character’s stubbornness with layers of pained love that he’s never been taught how to express.

My question is about the first part of the sentence. why does it read "... he abandon.." instead of "he abandons"?

And I'm not sure about the meaning of "defaults to self-righteousness".

Comment: It's the subjunctive. See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/165857/i-demand-that-he-leave-or-leaves).

Comment: I particularly recommend [the answer by Araucaria](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/165908) to the question linked above – the top-voted answer can be ignored as it's inaccurate. (Note to mods: please don't edit out my caveat again.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a *subjunctive* phrase, and more specifically, a *mandative subjunctive* one.

Subjunctive phrases are mostly used when talking about hypothetical situations or wishes, as follows:

> If I **were** a boy, I think I could understand.
>   I wish that what he said **were** true...
>   The report recommends that he **face** the tribunal.

When using subjunctive, bare infinitive is used (apart from *were*), like your example. Be aware, though, of [mandative and non-mandative](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/165857/i-demand-that-he-leave-or-leaves) subjunctive (as pointed out by Peter Shor).

Comment: What you have described above is true of written English and American English. In informal British English, on the other hand, "abandons" is possible.

Answer (score 1):

In Standard American English, a bare infinitive, i.e., one without the infinitive marker "to," is used in the objective clause after verbs such as "demand, "require," etc. So "abandon" is correct.

In formal British English, you would see "should abandon." In informal British English, you would see the indicative form of the verb used. Therefore, "abandons" is also correct.

The following is taken from [The Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/demand):

> • In everyday English, you demand that someone does something:
>
> I demand that he **apologizes**.
>
> • In formal English, you demand that someone do something, using the
>   base form of the verb (=the infinitive without ‘to’):
>
> His opponents are demanding that he **resign**.
>
> **✗**Don’t say: demand someone to do something
>
> • You use the base form of the verb when talking about the past:
>
> They demanded that he **resign**.
>
> • In everyday English, people also say:
>
> They demanded that he **resigned**.
>
> • You demand that someone should do something:
>
> His opponents demanded that he **should resign**.